# Leave Request Approval List/Calendar/Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online

My main goal is to create three things:

1.) Create a Leave Request List

2.) Create an automated approval process workflow

3.) Create a Calendar Style List to display approved leaves for employees

What I have so far is I have created the list called TestingLeaveRequest. This list has the columns Name(Person or Group), Start Date (Date), End Date (Date), Day Status (Choice field[Full or Partial Day(s)]), Total Hours (Number), Reason (Multiple Lines of Text), and Approval (Choice field[Yes or No])(instead of Choice field, should this be a task outcome field?).

Once an employee or user fills out this form, an approval (task?) email will be sent to two managers, either or can approve it or deny it. After the list item has been created and the manager(s) are notified of the request, the workflow also sends an email to the user who created the list item telling them their leave request has been submitted for review.

Once the manager approves or denies the leave request, (in this case lets say approved) the user who created the list item is notified via email that their request has been approved and then whichever days they selected for leave will be marked on the calendar.

I have made workflows before, but I cannot seem to figure out the approval workflow. I also have no idea to implement the calendar, I have done plenty of research and can't find any good examples or anything. I have the list down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using MS flow instead of using sharepoint designer since it is much more easier to configure plus has more functionalities for future integration and improvements.

MS flow has a template flow which does pretty much what you want to do ... you would have to modify it little bit

Please check the one here :-
https://us.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/906bdcc238bb49f19879ab62a88f3aa7/request-manager-approval-for-leave-requests/

You would have to add blocks for setting up the calendar... and personalized email notification

Fore more info please refer this youtube link which seems to do what you want
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oi8PFX4CNz4

Comment: I tried this answer and followed the video the whole way through. Even if you choose approve it still rejects it?

Comment: In the approval block please change  the left hand side of the condition from "Response" to "Outcome". Also be sure to set the value to "Approve" and not "Approved". I've made similar mistake earlier :)